# Save and load stroke from an InkCanvas to a variable

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to save all the strokes of an `InkCanvas` in a variable (not a file) and later load them in the `InkCanvas`when the user needs it. The problem is that I get an unknown error every time I try to load the strokes.

This is the code I'm using to load them:

```
            foreach (InkStroke stroke in StrokesList)
        {
            var strokeBuilder = new InkStrokeBuilder();
            strokeBuilder.SetDefaultDrawingAttributes(stroke.DrawingAttributes);
            System.Numerics.Matrix3x2 matr = stroke.PointTransform;
            IReadOnlyList<InkPoint> inkPoints = stroke.GetInkPoints();
            InkStroke stk = strokeBuilder.CreateStrokeFromInkPoints(inkPoints, matr);
            InkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.AddStroke(stk);
        }
```

I also tried `InkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.AddStrokes(StrokesList);` but it doesn't work either

**EDIT:** I'm saving the strokes like this:             `IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> StrokesList = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you require is storing and then restoring the strokes, I recommend using [StrokeContainer.SaveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStrokeContainer_SaveAsync_) to a [InMemoryRandomAccessStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream) and then just loading that with [StrokeContainer.LoadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStrokeContainer_LoadAsync_).

Comment: private async void saveState()
        {
                await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(undoStream);
        } This code returns a NullReferenceException, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is your `undoStream` an instance of `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`?

Comment: Yes, I declare it like this: private InMemoryRandomAccessStream undoStream;

Comment: you do need to create an instance of it, it won't do that for you! `private InMemoryRandomAccessStream undoStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream()`

Comment: Now I get a System.Exception when trying to load from the stream:         `private async void loadState()
        {
            await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.LoadAsync(undoStream);
        }`

Comment: Make sure you call `undoStream.Seek(0)` before loading it!